# Error C2511 with QtLogger

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, exiv2

Good morning,

I'm currently working on Qt project ( software used: VS 2010), in my QLogger.cpp, i have an C2511 error with my function addDestination, but i don't know why, because all my functions are correctly used.
I'm coding in release mode, because it doesn't work on debug mode.

*Here the full message error :*

Error   1   error C2511: 'bool QLogger::QLoggerManager::addDestination(const QString &,const QString &,QLogger::LogLevel)' : overloaded member function not found in 'QLogger::QLoggerManager'  C:\Users\gdeca_000\Desktop\qt-coding\QLogger\QLogger.cpp    104

*Here the .h Code :*

```
    static QString levelToText(const LogLevel &level);
            /**
             * @brief This method creates a QLoogerWriter that stores the name of the file and the log
             * level assigned to it. Here is added to the map the different modules assigned to each
             * log file. The method returns <em>false</em> if a module is configured to be stored in
             * more than one file.
             *
             * @param fileDest The file name and path to print logs.
             * @param modules The modules that will be stored in the file.
             * @param level The maximum level allowed.
             * @return Returns true if any error have been done.
             */


            // HERE THE DEFINITION OF ADDDESTINATION
            bool addDestination(const QString &fileDest, const QString &module, LogLevel level);
            bool addDestination(const QString &fileDest, const QStringList &modules, LogLevel level);
            // HERE THE DEFINITION OF ADDDESTINATION


            /**
             * @brief Gets the QLoggerWriter instance corresponding to the module <em>module</em>.
             * @param module The module we look for.
             * @return Retrns a pointer to the object.
             */
            QLoggerWriter * getLogWriter(const QString &module) { return moduleDest.value(module); }
            /**
             * @brief This method closes the logger and the thread it represents.
             */
            void closeLogger();
            /**
             * @brief Mutex to make the method thread-safe.
             */
            QMutex mutex;

        private:
            /**
             * @brief Instance of the class.
             */
            static QLoggerManager *INSTANCE;
            /**
             * @brief Map that stores the module and the file it is assigned.
             */
            QMap<QString,QLoggerWriter*> moduleDest;
            /**
             * @brief Default builder of the class. It starts the thread.
             */
            QLoggerManager();
    };
}
#endif // QLOGGER_H
```

*Here the .cpp Code :*

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "QLogger.h"
    namespace QLogger
{
    void QLog_Trace(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, TraceLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_Debug(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, DebugLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_Info(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, InfoLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_Warning(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, WarnLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_Error(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, ErrorLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_Fatal(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QLog_(module, FatalLevel, message);
    }

    void QLog_(const QString &module, LogLevel level, const QString &message)
    {
        QLoggerManager *manager = QLoggerManager::getInstance();

        QMutexLocker(&manager->mutex);

        QLoggerWriter *logWriter = manager->getLogWriter(module);

        if (logWriter && logWriter->getLevel() <= level)
                logWriter->write(module,message);
    }

    //QLoggerManager
    QLoggerManager * QLoggerManager::INSTANCE = NULL;

    QLoggerManager::QLoggerManager() : QThread(), mutex(QMutex::Recursive)
    {
        start();
    }

    QLoggerManager * QLoggerManager::getInstance()
    {
        if (!INSTANCE)
            INSTANCE = new QLoggerManager();

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    QString QLoggerManager::levelToText(const LogLevel &level)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case TraceLevel: return "Trace";
            case DebugLevel: return "Debug";
            case InfoLevel: return "Info";
            case WarnLevel: return "Warning";
            case ErrorLevel: return "Error";
            case FatalLevel: return "Fatal";
            default: return QString();
        }
    }
    // bug error C2511
    // Declaration in H

    // bool addDestination                (const QString &fileDest, const QString &module, LogLevel level);

       bool QLoggerManager::addDestination(const QString &fileDest, const QString &module, LogLevel level) 
    {
        QLoggerWriter *log;

        if (!moduleDest.contains(module))
        {
            log = new QLoggerWriter(fileDest,level);
            moduleDest.insert(module, log);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

//  bool addDestination                (const QString &fileDest, const QStringList &modules, LogLevel level); // declaration in H
    bool QLoggerManager::addDestination(const QString &fileDest, const QStringList &modules, LogLevel level)
    {
        QLoggerWriter *log;
        foreach (QString module, modules)
        {
            if (!moduleDest.contains(module))
            {
                log = new QLoggerWriter(fileDest,level);
                moduleDest.insert(module, log);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void QLoggerManager::closeLogger()
    {
        exit(0);
        deleteLater();
    }

    QLoggerWriter::QLoggerWriter(const QString &fileDestination, LogLevel level)
    {
        m_fileDestination = fileDestination;
        m_level = level;
    }

    void QLoggerWriter::write(const QString &module, const QString &message)
    {
        QString _fileName = m_fileDestination;

        int MAX_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

        QDir dir(QDir::currentPath());
        if (!dir.exists("logs"))
            dir.mkdir("logs");

        QFile file(_fileName);
        QString toRemove = _fileName.section('.',-1);
        QString fileNameAux = _fileName.left(_fileName.size() - toRemove.size()-1);
        bool renamed = false;
        QString newName = fileNameAux + "_%1__%2.log";

        //Renomenem l'arxiu si està ple
        if (file.size() >= MAX_SIZE)
        {
            //Creem un fixer nou
            QDateTime currentTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
            newName = newName.arg(currentTime.date().toString("dd_MM_yy")).arg(currentTime.time().toString("hh_mm_ss"));
            renamed = file.rename(_fileName, newName);

        }

        file.setFileName(_fileName);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append))
        {
            QTextStream out(&file);
            QString dtFormat = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz");

            if (renamed)
                out << QString("%1 - Previuous log %2\n").arg(dtFormat).arg(newName);

            QString logLevel = QLoggerManager::levelToText(m_level);
            QString text = QString("[%1] [%2] {%3} %4\n").arg(dtFormat).arg(logLevel).arg(module).arg(message);
            out << text;
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project. In your code everyting seems all right.

Comment: I did it more than two times and it did not solve my error

Comment: Can you provide full code of .h?

Comment: You got the full .h, it is the one i use

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, it was due to a mistake in the file path :)